# How do I check for intersect of two many-to-many tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to create a query but I'm currently struggling with this problem.
I have users who speak many languages and belong to many teams.
I have teams with many users and therefore many languages are spoken.

I want to get all users who speak at least one of the languages of the team where `team.id = 10`
If there is a match I want to get all of the languages the user is speaking, not only the intersect between `team_has_languages` and `user_has_languages`.
The query I'm currently using is:

```
select * from user 
inner join user_has_language on user.id = user_has_language.user_id
where user_has_language.language_id in 
(select language_id from team inner join team_has_language on team.id = team_has_language.team_id
where team.id = 10);
```

The query works but only gives me the intersect of the languages.
Does someone have any idea?

I'm working with MySQL.

Here is a diagram of my database.
[image: my database]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one method:

```
select u.*, ul.*
from user u join
     user_has_language ul
     on ul.id = ul.user_id
where u.id in (select ul.user_id
               from user_has_language ul
               where ul.language_id in
                     (select thl.language_id
                      from team_has_language thl
                      where thl.team_id = 10
                     )
              );
```